# How to exclude something that is in the result?

Tags: regex

For string `"Mark, -100"` I'm using

```
(?: +)?(.*)\b(?: +)?,(?: +)?(-?(?: +)?\d+)
```

to match and capture the name and integer as separate groups.

But for string `"Mark, - 100"` it also captures the space between the '-' and '1', so the captured integer is `"- 100"` instead of `"-100"`.

How can I make it capture `"-100"` in this case?

Comment: You can't. Regex doesn't "do" anything to the input; it just matches parts of it. To *modify* the matched text, you need app code. What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @Bohemian I was using Java for this content. I had to replace all " " to "" for group2 in order to get "-100" instead of "- 100". Just curious. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to extract a number with an optional minus sign with optional spaces before digits:

```
String num = str.replaceAll(".*(-)? *(\\d+).*", "$1$2");
```